# Update a project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, project, updates

**Context :** I have finished and have deployed my WPF *(C#)* project but later I have added some new features.

---

**Question :** How I can update the published version with only the newest features. Do I have to manually code a feature that check files and download only the newest ones or there is some simple tool built-in Visual Studio to do that for me?

Comment: Have a look at click once deployments

Comment: What kind of project (MVC, WPF, Typescript, ...) is this? Are you using .Net Core?

Comment: Will research about ClickOnce deployment i've heard about that but never searched about it.

@JeroenHeiher mainly WPF projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend first understanding the difference between continuous integration and continuous deployment. 
[continuous-deployment-vs-continuous-integration](https://stackify.com/continuous-delivery-vs-continuous-deployment-vs-continuous-integration/)

Then you have to opt a continuous deployment strategy. You can choose between various tools like [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) and so on. Here's a list: [Tools](https://stackify.com/top-continuous-integration-tools/)

You can also look at some opensource projects like [ShareX](https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX). You can learn a lot from the way their projects are released and updated.